# Mysql statement Echo works in PHPMYADMIN but wont work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The first SQL statement works and I get the iid.  The second mysql query returns false.  If I past the echo of the second mysql statement directly into phpmyadmin, it works.  Using mysql root user.

```
function keyShipment($client_id ,$pro ,$scac ,$carrier_name ,$mode ,$origin_name ,$origin_add1 ,$origin_add2 ,$origin_city ,$origin_state ,$origin_zip ,$origin_country ,$dest_name ,$dest_add1 ,$dest_add2 ,$dest_city ,$dest_state ,$dest_zip ,$dest_country ,$delivery_date ,$ship_date ,$terms ,$bol_no ,$po_no ,$so_no ,$misc1 ,$misc2 ,$invoice_date ,$invoice_no ,$gl_code ,$gross ,$disc ,$fuel ,$i_o ,$bol_items ,$inv_items ,$acc_codes,$date_entered,$entered_by)
{

    //first populate the status table and get the iid
    global $db,$db_table_prefix;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ship_status`(`pro`, `status`, `client_id`) VALUES ('$pro', 'keyed', '$client_id');";
    echo $sql;  //testing only
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
    $iid = mysql_insert_id();



    //now to populate the detail table
    $sql_detail = "INSERT INTO `ship_detail`(`scac`, `carrier_name`, `mode`, `origin_name`, `origin_add1`, `origin_add2`, `origin_city`, `origin_state`, `origin_zip`, `origin_country`, `dest_name`, `dest_add1`, `dest_add2`, `dest_city`, `dest_state`, `dest_zip`, `dest_country`, `iid`, `delivery_date`, `ship_date`, `terms`, `bol_no`, `po_no`, `so_no`, `misc1`, `misc2`, `date_entered`, `invoice_date`, `invoice_no`, `entered_by`, `gl_code`, `i_o`) VALUES ('$scac','$carrier_name', '$mode', '$origin_name', '$origin_add1', '$origin_add2', '$origin_city', '$origin_state', '$origin_zip', '$origin_country', '$dest_name', '$dest_add1', '$dest_add2', '$dest_city', '$dest_state', '$dest_zip', '$dest_country', '$iid', '$delivery_date', '$ship_date', '$terms', '$bol_no', '$po_no', '$so_no', '$misc1', '$misc2', '$date_entered', '$invoice_date', '$invoice_no','$entered_by', '$gl_code', '$i_o');";
    echo $sql_detail;  //testing only
    $result_detail = returnResults($sql_detail);
    var_dump($result_detail);
}
```

Comment: What database driver are you using here? `mysql_insert_id` implies `mysql_query`, yet when you execute the query you're using some wrapper `sql_query`. Don't forget `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface that's being removed from PHP. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Where is values of those column in you second Query? You are not passing any value in your second query. And trying to insert.

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements. Check for error after every SQL command. post the error message.

Comment: I am using the user_pie project to manage my users.  I am using it's wrapper to send MYSQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to PDO and it's working now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not run the 2nd query.

```
$result = $db->sql_query($sql_detail);
```